# Calling AZURE-API from standalone vb application

Tags: vb.net, azure-api-apps

Well I have a problem. The program that I need to modify was created from `visual studio 2005` and it's a standalone `POS (Point Of Sale)`. Now they want me to add some features from that which is calling a `WEB API(Azure) with POST method` that will store `customers information`.

I'm looking for any reference to integrate the API from the application, it seems that all I got was not supported by visual studio 2005 and can't get it to work.

BTW below is the `HTTP request` sample

```
POST http://sampleapi.azure-api.net/clientprof/dev/pos/transaction/saverec/{mobileNo}/{FullName} HTTP/1.1

Host: sampleapi.azure-api.net

Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: ••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••
```

Any suggestions and help would be greatly appreciated on how to integrate this on the application. - THANKS

Comment: You want help with code that can call the REST API? I'm sorry I don't follow

Comment: Yes actually. I do need help with that. What I did was created a c# console application using visual studio 2017. I successfully Call the server upon checking. Now how can I put value on this line `{mobileNo}/{FullName}`